# Do Spring transactions propagate through new instantiations

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I'm working on a bunch of legacy code written by people before me and I'm confused about a particular kind of setup and wonder if this has ever worked to begin with.

There is a managed bean in spring that has a transactional method.

```
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
  public boolean updateDraftAndLivePublicationUsingFastDocumentsOfMySite(List<FastDocumentLite> fastDocumentLites, Long mySiteId) throws Exception { ... }
```

Now inside that method I find new instantiations calling update methods fe:

```
 boolean firstFeed = new MySiteIdUpdate(publishing, siteDao, siteDomainService).update(siteId, fastDocumentLites.get(0).getMySiteId());
```

From my understanding on IOC this new class isn't managed by spring , it's just a variable in the bean.  Now going further inside the update method you see another service gets called.

```
  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
  public void activateSubdomainForSite(Long siteId, boolean activationOfSite)
```

So if there is a transaction open it should be propagated into this service.  But here is what I don't get if that MySiteIdUpdate object isn't managed by spring does the first transaction move forward to the activateSubdomainForSite method ??  Or is another transaction being opened here.  I looked in the logs and I believe it to be the latter but I rather ask the experts for a second oppinion before I proclame this legacy code to be complete rubbish to the project lead.  I'm suffering with a StaleStateException somewhere further down the road and I'm hoping this has anything to do with it.

Comment: 1) How obtain `MySiteIdUpdate` the instance of the class that contains `activateSubdomainForSite`? (it this the `siteDao` reference?) --- 2) does `MySiteIdUpdate.update` create a new thread, or does it just invoke `activateSubdomainForSite`

Comment: siteDao is an injected instance in the managed bean.  It's just an @Repository that does hibernate queries.  It's nothing special.  It gets passed in the constructor of the class that has the update() method.

Comment: From my first impression, I would say the code is correct, and the second `@Transactional` should reuse the transaction. - But a better justification depends on the answers to the questions above.

Comment: what is with the second question: new threads?

Comment: I made a copy paste mistake the domainService gets injected together with the siteDao into the class calling the update.  domainService is a bean injected in the parent bean and is an annotated @Service.  I need to debug again for the threads question.  I can't right now due to circumstances, but I believe they all run on the same thread if I read the logging right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code is correct, and the second `@Transactional` should reuse the existing transaction.

Because:

1) Spring Transaction handling is done either by Proxies or by AspectJ advices. If it is done by Proxies then it is required that `MySiteIdUpdate` invoke an instance that is injected (this is what you did). If you use AspectJ, then it should work anyway.

2) The association Transactions to the code that use is done by the Thread, this mean, as long as you "are" in the thread which started the transaction you can use it. (you do not start an new thread, so it should work)

---

An other way to explain: It is perfect legal when you have some method in your call hierarchy that does not belong to an spring bean. This should not make the transaction handling fail.

Comment: I opened full logging and ran it again and I believe you are right.  The transaction gets reused, that is one worry less for me.  Now I still have to find that stalestate in a transaction that seems to go on for ages ... I hate undocumented legacy code ...